# Twin Macro Conditionally Set Text Color

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to conditionally set the text color based on payments status, but I'm having trouble getting the color to work. I've looked through some of the docs, but I can't seem to find a way to do this, unless it's not possible. Code below.

```
const status = {
    processing: {
        color: 'text-yellow-500',
        lable: "Processing"
    },
    succeeded: {
        color: 'text-green-600',
        label: "Succeeded"
    },
    failed: {
        color: 'text-red-500',
        label: "Failed"
    },
    requires_action: {
        color: 'text-orange-500',
        lable: "Action Required"
    },
}
<span css={[tw`${status[payment.status].color}`]}>
    {status[payment.status].label}
</span>
```

Comment: Could you clarify if you're using any additional libraries specifically how you're using the `css` attribute and `tw`  along with what they do, as these are not available in vanilla react and so I'm not familiar with them. 
**The code above works, if you change `css` to `className`**

Comment: @RohanThacker I inherited the project, but it's using the twin macro package https://www.npmjs.com/package/twin.macro - I see some things about conditional styles, but I can't figure out how to make the above work.

Comment: Well after a quick reproduction of the code above on StackBlitz, its seems as though `tw` can only accept plain strings in-order to work. 
So If my understand is correct this is probably not possible using `tw` and `css` as the code above shows. 
Since you're not using any props in your css. You can resolve the color's class and pass the value into `className`. At the moment this work around is all that comes to mind.